# Google Apps Script: Replace soft line break for hard line break

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have this script that replaces text in a Google Doc using info from a Google Spreadsheet.

**Input**

The input is a cell inside a Google Sheet that has soft line breaks.
[image]

I would like to convert  those soft line breaks into hard line breaks.

**Solution so far**

I'm able to find the soft line break I write on the Google Spreadsheet by searching for /\n/g. However when I try to replace \n with \r I'm still getting soft line breaks.

```
demo_content = ss.getRangeByName("SectionContentsDemo").getValue().toString().replace(/\n/g,'\r\n'),
template_doc_body.replaceText("{{Section Contents - Demo}}", demo_content);
```

I'm able to validate that it's a soft line break instead of a hard one because all the lines in the Google Doc paragraph are indented, as a soft line break would behave.

[image]

Anyone has an idea on how to replace the soft line breaks into hard ones?

Thanks

Sources:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAU0-COifUd2j1PA5_td3tuDnBSqcnOo_4-cMqiAFUI

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dQaDipbs3BkMYcHx_1s6qFjyltmLtbTrzzlmVX3Cl1o/

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In your question, the upper and the bottom images are the sample input situation and the sample output situation, respectively?

Comment: Hello Tanaike. My apologies if it wasn't understood correctly. The first image is how it is supossed to look, an example. The second image is what I'm getting after finding and replaceing \n with \r. In my output, the new paragraphs come with a soft line break, instead of a hard one.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that the upper image is the situation of your current issue. The bottom image is the sample putput situation you expect? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample input situation?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike. The top image its the desired output, and the bottom image is the current output. I've updated the question in hopes that  its easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: From what I know, it is impossible to find hard breaks with regex with `replaceText`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I found the soft line break from the spreadsheet cell, however when placing that info into the Google doc I cannot find the way to replace those soft line breaks for new paragraphs

Comment: @Tanaike I updated the question in hopes that I exprese myself better. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I understood that your upper image is the sample input situation. In your question, your lower image is the sample output situation you expect? If my understanding is correct, I cannot understand about the difference between the values of the cell "F2" and your sample output situation. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm not really sure if this is correct but I recorded a video hehe
https://www.loom.com/share/68c4979f8b274b5c88a82839faa7dd64

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the simple sample Spreadsheet and Document for correctly replicating your situation?

Comment: Sure! I'll add them to the quesiton

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Now I noticed your replying. I apologize for this. From your additional information and your updated question, I proposed a sample script for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following script in your question and your sample input and output situations,

```
demo_content = ss.getRangeByName("SectionContentsDemo").getValue().toString().replace(/\n/g,'\r\n'),
template_doc_body.replaceText("{{Section Contents - Demo}}", demo_content);
```

I thought that when the value including the line break is replaced with `{{Section Contents - Demo}}` in your Google Document, the indent might be changed after 2nd line. So, in this case, how about using Docs API? When the Docs API is used, a sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var template_id = '###'; // Please set your template Google Document ID.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var value = ss.getRangeByName("SectionContentsDemo").getValue();
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(template_id).makeCopy().getId();
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({
    requests: [
      {
        replaceAllText: {
          replaceText: value,
          containsText: { matchCase: true, text: "{{Section Contents - Demo}}" }
        }
      }]
  }, documentId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the value is retrieved from the named range of `SectionContentsDemo` of Spreadsheet, and the retrieved value is replaced with `{{Section Contents - Demo}}` in the document. In this case, it seems that the indent is followed to `{{Section Contents - Demo}}`.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replacealltextrequest)

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Although I'm curious about why working it out in this way delivered the desired result. Is it because of the Advanced Google Services?
I could have never reached to this answer on my own even if my live depended on it
Thanks!

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When I checked your Google Document, it seems that when the text including the line breaks is replaced with the value on your Google Document, the indent of inserted texts follows the replaced text. But, after 2nd line of the text, the indent is nested. I'm not sure whether this is the current specification. From this situation, I tested it using Docs API. By this, I confirmed that the indent of all lines of the text follows the replaced text. So I proposed this method.

Comment: oh, I kind of understand now, not all but at least something.. hehe. Thanks again Tanaike!